# stringvariable.set method to transfer a string into Tkinter from a Python function

Tags: tkinter, python-3.4

I am following an ingenious (based on code examples given in "stackoverflow" and elsewhere method for transferring datetime.utcnow content around a Tkinter app which comprises many frame pages. The method that I have used is to define a consistently named timelabel object on each frame and to declare global time1 and time1=tk.StringVar() on the first (HomePage) frame. My function makes a string containing a time-stamp that is formatted using the strftime method as shown in the following

```
time1=datetime.utcnow()
time1=time1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time1=('Time: ' + time1)

def second_tick():
    global time2, time1, stroke_time
    current_time = datetime.utcnow()
    current_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    time2 = ('Time: ' + current_time)
    if time2 != time1:
        time1.set(time2)
        time1=time2
        print(time2, current_time[14:19])
# calls itself every 200 milliseconds (5 times a second)
app.after(200, second_tick)
```

When I run this code it fails with the message given:
time1.set(time2)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

However when I simplify the function to the form below the code runs perfectly:

```
def second_tick():
    global time2, time1, stroke_time
    current_time = datetime.utcnow()
    current_time = current_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    time2 = ('Time: ' + current_time)
    time1.set(time2)
    print(time2, current_time[14:19])
    # calls itself every 200 milliseconds (5 times a second)
    app.after(200, second_tick)
```

I want to use the former version to reduce the need for screen refresh at higher than one second rate (and for other reasons too). Could anyone please explain why the time1.set(time2) instruction is working in the simplified version and not with the preferred version. 
Thank-you in advance,
Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
time1=datetime.utcnow()
time1=time1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
time1=('Time: ' + time1)
#also in second_tick as well
time1=time2
```

In these lines you are changing `time1` to `string`. Instead of assigning it this way, set `StringVar`s value to that string.

```
time1.set('Time: ' + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

EDIT: *OPs solution for his/her own problem(taken from comments)*

```
time2=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
def second_tick(): 
    global time2, time3, stroke_time 
    time3=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    if time3 != time2: 
        time1.set('Time: ' + time3) 
        time2=time3 
        print(time2, time3) 
    # calls itself every 200 milliseconds (5 times a second) 
    app.after(200, second_tick)
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried what you suggest and I'm getting the same failure report:          time1.set('Time: ' + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'

Comment: @Oliver logic is the same. Don't assing string to time1 at any place in your code. Look for all `time1 = `and correct them in your code with `.set()`

Comment: Thank-you for this. I presume that we still have to declare the variable time1 as something? What do you suggest?

Comment: I have solved this problem following your logic. Thank-you. For everyone's benefit the working code is structured as:

Comment: time2=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

def second_tick():
    global time2, time3, stroke_time
    time3=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    if time3 != time2:
        time1.set('Time: ' + time3)
        time2=time3
        print(time2, time3)
    # calls itself every 200 milliseconds (5 times a second)
    app.after(200, second_tick)

Comment: @Oliver Added your code to solution. Hopefully indentation is OK.